# How to differentiate between method and function in a decorator?

Tags: python, decorator

I want to write a decorator that acts differently depending on whether it is applied to a function or to a method.

```
def some_decorator(func):
    if the_magic_happens_here(func): # <---- Point of interest
        print 'Yay, found a method ^_^ (unbound jet)'
    else:
        print 'Meh, just an ordinary function :/'
    return func

class MyClass(object):
    @some_decorator
    def method(self):
        pass

@some_decorator
def function():
    pass
```

I tried `inspect.ismethod()`, `inspect.ismethoddescriptor()` and `inspect.isfunction()` but no luck. The problem is that a method actually is neither a bound nor an unbound method but an ordinary function as long as it is accessed from within the class body.

What I really want to do is to delay the actions of the decorator to the point the class is actually instantiated because I need the methods to be callable in their instance scope. For this, I want to mark methods with an attribute and later search for these attributes when the `.__new__()` method of `MyClass` is called. The classes for which this decorator should work are required to inherit from a class that is under my control. You can use that fact for your solution.

In the case of a normal function the delay is not necessary and the decorator should take action immediately. That is why I wand to differentiate these two cases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would rely on the convention that functions that will become methods have a first argument named `self`, and other functions don't.  Fragile, but then, there's no really solid way.

So (pseudocode as I have comments in lieu of what you want to do in either case...):

```
import inspect
import functools

def decorator(f):
  args = inspect.getargspec(f)
  if args and args[0] == 'self':
     # looks like a (future) method...
  else:
     # looks like a "real" function
     @functools.wraps(f)
     def wrapper  # etc etc
```

One way to make it a bit more solid, as you say all classes involved inherit from a class under your control, is to have that class provide a metaclass (which will also of course be inherited by said classes) which checks things at the end of the class body.  Make the wrapped function accessible e.g. by `wrapper._f = f` and the metaclass's `__init__` can check that all wrapped methods did indeed have `self` as the first argument.

Unfortunately there's no easy way to check that *other* functions (non-future-methods) being wrapped *didn't* have such a first argument, since you're not in control of the environment in that case.  The decorator might check for "top-level" functions (ones whose `def` is a top-level statement in their module), via the `f_globals` (globals dict, i.e., module's dict) and `f_name` attributes of the function -- if the function's such a global presumably it won't later be assigned as an attribute of the class (thereby becoming a future-method anyway;-) so the `self` named first arg, if there, can be diagnosed as wrong and warned about (while still treating the function as a real function;-).

One alternative would be to do the decoration in the decorator itself under the hypothesis of a real function, but also make available the original function object as `wrapper._f`.  Then, the metaclass's `__init__` can re-do the decoration for all functions in the class body that it sees have been marked this way.  This approach is much more solid than the convention-relying one I just sketched, even with the extra checks.  Still, something like

```
class Foo(Bar): ... # no decorations

@decorator
def f(*a, **k): ...

Foo.f = f   # "a killer"... function becomes method!
```

would still be problematic -- you could try intercepting this with a `__setattr__` in your metaclass (but then other assignments to class attributes after the `class` statement can become problematic).

The more the user's code has freedom to do funky things (and Python generally leaves the programmer a lot of such freedom), the harder time your "framework-y" code has keeping things under tight control instead, of course;-).

Comment: The metaclass approach did it, thanks! I can undo the actions of the decorator for methods found by `MetaClass.__init__` on definition-time and reattach the decorator in `BaseClass.__new__` after initialization, this time using the bound instance method instead of the soon-to-be-a-method unbound function.

Comment: I think it should be ``args=inspect.getargspec(f).args``

Comment: Just for the record for future readers: The code is deprecated and the approach is outdated. (Obviously the post is pretty old.) Use the approach by @kentwait.

Comment: In modern python: `inspect.getfullargspec`

Comment: Also, slightly faster approach: `if next(iter(inspect.signature(func).parameters.keys()), None) in ('self', 'cls')`

Answer (score 16):

From Python 3.3 onwards by using [PEP 3155](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/):

```
def some_decorator(func):
    if func.__name__ != func.__qualname__:
        print('Yay, found a method ^_^ (unbound jet)')
    else:
        print('Meh, just an ordinary function :/')
    return func
```

A method `x` of class `A` will have a `__qualname__` that is `A.x` while a function `x` will have a `__qualname__` of `x`.

Comment: The modern approach!

Comment: Amazing idea! You should also take note on nested functions, so the test would be `func.__name__ != func.__qualname__.split('>.')[-1]`.

Comment: Also, `@staticmethod` functions does not have "self" argument. Be prepared, look like general function, but has `__name__ = classname.method`

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to have the magic happen where you choose which wrapper to return, or can you defer the magic until the function is actually called?
You could always try a parameter to your decorator to indicate which of the two wrappers it should use, like

```
def some_decorator( clams ):
   def _mydecor(func ):
       @wraps(func)
       def wrapping(*args....)
          ...
       return wrapping
   def _myclassdecor(func):
       @wraps(func)
       .....

   return _mydecor if clams else _myclassdecor
```

The other thing that I might suggest is to create a metaclass and define the **init** method in the metaclass to look for methods decorated with your decorator and revise them accordingly, like Alex hinted at.  Use this metaclass with your base class, and since all the classes that will use the decorator will inherit from the base class, they'll also get the metaclass type and use its **init** as well.

Comment: The metaclass approach did it :) Your solution works, but I can only 'accept' a single answer and Alex was the first one, sorry. Stackoverflow should allow to 'accept' more than one answer...

Answer (score -4):

You just need to check to see if the function being decorated has an `im_func` attribute. If it does, then it is a method. If it doesn't then it is a function.

**Note** that the code sample below does the detection at call time but you can do it at decoration time as well. Just move the `hasattr` check to the outer decorator generator.

```
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Dec  7 2009, 18:45:15) 
[GCC 4.4.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def deco(f):
...   def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
...     if hasattr(f, 'im_func'):
...       print 'method'
...     else:
...       print 'function'
...   return _wrapper
... 
>>> deco(lambda x: None)()
function
>>> def f(x):
...   return x + 5
... 
>>> deco(f)()
function
>>> class A:
...   def f(self, x):
...     return x + 5
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> deco(a.f)()
method
>>> deco(A.f)()
method
>>>
```

**Edit**

Oh snap! And I get it totally wrong. I *so* should have read Alex's post more thoroughly.

```
>>> class B:
...   @deco
...   def f(self, x):
...     return x +5
... 
>>> b = B()
>>> b.f()
function
```